# Saving a comma delimited file as txt, getting strange character

Tags: c#, asp.net, export-to-excel

I am retrieving data from the SQL database and saving it '.txt' as a comma delimited file using a Web Application as developing environment.
The only problem I have is that at the start of the first column it add some garbage characters.

Ex. ¼¤Date, Time

Tried to use `Encoding.ASCII` and new `UTF8Encoding(false)` but solved the bug.

But the rest of the data is perfect. The code below is the one used to save the data.

```
        System.IO.StringWriter sWriter;
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

        sWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter(sb);
        string Str;

        for (int k = 0; k < (grdGridView.Columns.Count); k++)
        {
            if (k == (grdGridView.Columns.Count) - 1)
                sWriter.Write(grdGridView.HeaderRow.Cells[k].Text);
            else
                sWriter.Write(grdGridView.HeaderRow.Cells[k].Text + ","); 
        }

        sWriter.WriteLine("");

        for (int i = 0; i < (grdGridView.Rows.Count); i++)
        {

            for (int j = 0; j < (grdGridView.Columns.Count); j++)
            {

                Str = (grdGridView.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text.ToString());

                if (Str == "&nbsp;")
                    Str = "";

                if (j != (grdGridView.Columns.Count) - 1)
                { Str = (Str + ","); }

                sWriter.Write(Str);
            }
            sWriter.WriteLine();
        }
        sWriter.Close();

        // Download File Directly to Web Server
        //string HtmlInfo = sWriter.ToString().Trim();
        string HtmlInfo = sWriter.ToString();
        string DocFileName = fileName1 + ".txt";
        string FilePathName = Server.MapPath("~/Download");
        FilePathName = FilePathName + "\\" + DocFileName;
        File.Delete(FilePathName);
        FileStream Fs = new FileStream(FilePathName, FileMode.Create);
        BinaryWriter BWriter = new BinaryWriter(Fs, Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8"));
        BWriter.Write(HtmlInfo);
        BWriter.Close();
        Fs.Close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 string HtmlInfo = sWriter.ToString();
 ....
 BinaryWriter BWriter = ...
 BWriter.Write(HtmlInfo);
```

Using a BinaryWriter makes little sense here. The characters you see are [the Length-prefix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yzxa6408%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) that is prependeded to a string by a BinaryWriter.

Use a TextWriter instead, or get the contents of sWriter as a `byte[]`.

Answer (score 3):

The leading characters are the unicode [Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8).

You can disable the output of the BOM by using `new UTF8Encoding(false)` instead of `Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8")`.

Comment: @HenkHolterman My mistake, you are right: it's a [length prefix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yzxa6408.aspx). I jumped the gun after I saw `GetEncoding("UTF-8")` and "there's junk at the start of my file", didn't even notice it was a `BinaryWriter`!

Answer (score 1):

try  Encoding.ASCII instead of .GetEncoding("UTF-8")